# Javascript Help me make this so it's DRY

Tags: javascript, loops, onclick, dry, getelementbyid

I would like to make this code DRY. I know I am repeating myself here and there must be a way to condense this code. The code is working and does what i want but I am trying to learn how to configure my code better. Can you please help?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpMKLX

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="num_wrapper">
        <div id="divNum_1"></div>
        <button id="btn_1"> Pick</button>
    </div>
    <div class="num_wrapper">
        <div id="divNum_2"></div>
        <button id="btn_2"> Pick</button>
    </div>
    <div class="num_wrapper">
        <div id="divNum_3"></div>
        <button id="btn_3"> Pick</button>
    </div>
    <div class="num_wrapper">
        <div id="divNum_4"></div>
        <button id="btn_4"> Pick</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var btnOne = document.getElementById("btn_1");
var btnTwo = document.getElementById("btn_2");
var btnThree = document.getElementById("btn_3");
var btnFour = document.getElementById("btn_4");

var divOne = document.getElementById("divNum_1");
var divTwo = document.getElementById("divNum_2");
var divThree = document.getElementById("divNum_3");
var divFour = document.getElementById("divNum_4");

function randomNum() {
    var num = Math.random() * 10;
    num = Math.floor(num);
    return num;
}

btnOne.onclick = function () {
    divOne.innerHTML = randomNum();
}

btnTwo.onclick = function () {
    divTwo.innerHTML = randomNum();
}

btnThree.onclick = function () {
    divThree.innerHTML = randomNum();
}

btnFour.onclick = function () {
    divFour.innerHTML = randomNum();
}
```

Comment: Can you use server side code?

Comment: No. Just javascript client side.

Comment: Can you change the HTML structure at all?  I am thinking that you don't need the numbered `id` for divNum_N and btn_N and use classes instead. For example, you can have a generic solution if your HTML structure is _"a div of class 'num_wrapper' which encloses exactly one div of class 'num_content' and a sibling button of class 'num_pick'"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addOnclick(index)
{
    //Get the button
    var button = document.getElementById( "btn_" + index );

    //Add listener
    button.addEventListener(
        "click",
        function () {
            document.getElementById( "divNum_" + index ).innerHTML = randomNum();
        }
    );
}

//Now call it
for ( var i = 1; i < 5; i++ ) addOnclick( i );
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zm1rmqpd/)

Comment: This looks good. I never knew you could do something like this.

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) addOnclick( i );

It actually doesn't makes sense to me. I thought you always needed to write the for loop with the { }.

Comment: @user3259232 What do you mean "like this"? Are there parts of the code you want more explanation of?

Comment: @user3259232 `if...else` and `for`, `while` can be written without brackets `{` **only** if they're one line statements.

Comment: @user3259232 Please mark this as the answer if it answers your question. If not, let me know how I can expand it.

Comment: @user3259232, thank you for your help. Do you mind if I ping you in the future if I have more questions?

Comment: @user3259232 Do you mean more questions about this? No problem, just add them here as a comment

Comment: @user3259232, I mean other questions I may have regarding javascript.

Comment: @user3259232 No problem, just post them as questions in stackoverflow (so others can learn from them too) and you can add my username in a comment and it'll "ping" me

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("div button");
var divs    = document.querySelectorAll("div.num_wrapper > div");

if( buttons.length != divs.length ) throw "different number of buttons vs divs";

for(var i=0; i<buttons.length;i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function() {
        divs[i].textContent = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );
    } 
}
```

- Repeated calls to `getElementbyId` replaced with `querySelectorAll`
- `textContent` used instead of the semi-standard `innerHTML`, it's also XSS-safe
- Elimination of `randomNum`

Comment: Your code is incorrect. You're setting the wrong "div"'s content. You're essentially adding a text ndoe next to the div he wants to hold the random value.

Comment: This is also a great solution.

Thanks!

Comment: @DonRhummy Please explain further, I don't understand. I'm setting `textContent` which is inside the div, not next to it.

Comment: @Dai You're setting `textContent` on the div with class `num_wrapper`. That's the `parent` of the div he wants to set the value of, for example with `id="divNum_3"`

Comment: @DonRhummy Ah, I didn't spot that. Thanks. I've changed my selector to target the child `<div>`.

Comment: @Dai np. One small bit: your new code does work, but if there's ever multiple child divs inside any one of those parent `num_wrapper` divs, then your code would fail. Looking for the `id` is safer.

Answer (score 0):

Without resorting to requiring unique IDs with matching number suffixes, this can be done with classes attached to the parts.  It can be done without classes also, using relative elements, but the classes make it clearer in my example.

I'll use your same CSS and basically the same structure as you, but with classes in place of the IDs being used.

The page structure is as described in my earlier comment:

> "a div of class 'num_wrapper' which encloses exactly one div of class 'num_content' and a sibling button of class 'num_pick'"

This gets all of the _num_pick_ buttons, then loops through them and attaches a *click* event handler to each.

The handler function uses `this` for the button that was clicked, gets the parent, then finds the `num_content` div within (*querySelector* can be used on any Node, not just *document.querySelector!*) and sets its textContent.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.num_pick");
for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        var cont = this.parentElement.querySelector("div.num_content")
        cont.textContent = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );
    });
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
 width:448px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.num_wrapper {
 margin:0 5px;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 float:left;
 border:1px solid #333;
 background-color:#ccc;
 position:relative;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:60px;
 text-align:center;
}
button {
 width:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:72px;
 left:0;
 font-size:20px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="num_wrapper">
        <div class="num_content"></div>
        <button class="num_pick"> Pick </button>
    </div>
    <div class="num_wrapper">
        <div class="num_content"></div>
        <button class="num_pick"> Pick </button>
    </div>
    <div class="num_wrapper">
        <div class="num_content"></div>
        <button class="num_pick"> Pick </button>
    </div>
    <div class="num_wrapper">
        <div class="num_content"></div>
        <button class="num_pick"> Pick </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works for as many repeated `num_wrapper` divs as you want, without having to change/update numbers in each `id`.